# How to Delete Strings that Start with Certain Characters in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex, string

I have strings of the following pattern showing up in an array:

```
"@SomeUselessText"
```

In this example, I'd like to get rid of all strings in my array that start with the character "@".

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
def array_purge(array)
  for array.each |item|
    item = item.gsub(/@.*/, "")
  end
end
```

However, this also gets rid of valid email address of the form:

```
"info@SomeSite.com"
```

...which I'd like to keep.

I'm guessing there is an elegant way of handling this. Perhaps using ".reject!"

Comment: Maybe you can use [`String#start_with?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-start_with-3F)

Comment: `grep` or `grep_v` maybe useful here too.

Comment: I doubt the code posted does anything (or ever understood by ruby parser.)

Comment: You accepted a wrong answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if there's a whitespace (`\s`) before or if it's the start of the string (`^`).

```
(?:\s|^)@.*
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/Eu4HKf/1)

If you only want to match word characters, then instead of using `.` you could use `\w`. Also note that `*` would still match just `"@"`, so you might want to use `+` instead to match at least one character.

```
(?:\s|^)@\w+
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/Eu4HKf/2)

Comment: `^` is **not** start of the string. It’s start of the line within string. `\A` is a proper start of the string matcher.

Comment: @mudasobwa only if the multiline flag is set, which it is not.

Comment: The requirement is "_get rid of all strings in my array that start with the character "@"_". This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 7):

The other suggested answers do not in fact purge the targeted items from the array; they merely replace the items with empty strings. More likely you want this:

```
def array_purge(array)
  array.reject! { |item| item.start_with?('@') }
end

>> array = ['Hello', '123', '@SomeUselessText', 'info@SomeSite.com']
>> array_purge(array)
=> ["Hello", "123", "info@SomeSite.com"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Enumerable#grep_v`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep_v) here

```
array = ['Hello', '123', '@SomeUselessText', 'info@SomeSite.com']
array.grep_v(/\A@/)
 #=> ["Hello", "123", "info@SomeSite.com"]
```

Comment: Thanks to moveson since I used his array for my example.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following regular expression [line] instead: `a.gsub(/^@.*/, "")`

The `^` means "from the start of the line"... so, it only matches if there's the start of the line, then the next character is an @

Comment: Never use `^` matcher in such a case. Use `\A` instead. `^` would match in `"abc\n@def"`.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, it results in an empty string.